# VueJs v-for how to check list undefined before continue

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, undefined, v-for

Refer to the template below, how to add condition to make sure the `menu` is not `undefined` inside the `v-for` attribute?

I've tried `v-for="menu?item in menu.items:[]"` and `v-for="item in menu?.items"` but neither works.

```
<div v-for="item in menu.items">{{item.text}}</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the div with the `v-for` directive within a `<template>` that checks for `menu` via `v-if`:

```
<template v-if="menu">
  <div v-for="item in menu.items">{{ item.text }}</div>
</template>
```

This way, the div inside the template won't be rendered if `menu` does not exist.

---

If you really want the check within the `v-for` statement, like you are attempting, it would look like this:

```
<div v-for="item in (menu ? menu.items : [])">{{ item.text }}</div>
```